# Collation Name got changed while migrating from Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I am a java j2ee developer. I do not know much about DBA knowledge. For our project there are two databases we use: Oracle 11g and Microsoft SQL Server 2012. After writing SQL script in oracle, when we migrated to SQL Server 2012, the collation name got changed from `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

In Oracle and SQL Server both, the collation we have kept default as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. But somehow after migration the script from Oracle to SQL Server, the collation name has changed.

Note: a few random tables got changed only. And we have not mentioned collation name anywhere for those tables in script.

Please help how need to resolve this issue so the collation name does not get change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the collation to change, it needs to have an initial value. What collation *did* you specify in the migration script, specifically the database & table generation part? If you didn't specify anything, the *server's* collation is used as the default. If you set up the server as `CI_AS`, the most common scenario, the result will be `CI_AS` too.

Comment: In short, the collation didn't change, it probably wasn't specified in the first place. How did you migrate? With a hand-written script? A tool? Did the tool offer any options for collations?